# Face recognition with USB Camera

Tags: usb, webcam, opencv

How would I go about using face recognition with a USB camera, NOT the Pi Camera Board? A link to a tutorial would be fine. I know it was possible with OpenCV, but is it still, and how?

**Edit**

Can I get it to just detect my face (only my face, no one else's) and when it does execute some code?

Comment: This would be a good link to start. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html You can take any example of opencv, since Rpi runs full fledge linux, it should work out of the box.

Comment: Maybe start here: https://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencv-and-camera-board-csi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sure possible to use a USB camera on RasPi. Try getting a good resolution camera. you can find some useful information in this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/).

Regarding detecting only your own face. You can use one of many image processing techniques. I recommend using Haar cascade classifier as it is the easiest and you can easily understand it.

In your case you have to train your own detector. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwievYrLm4fOAhVDpx4KHTPFA0YQtwIIKDAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DWEzm7L5zoZE&usg=AFQjCNGd5WzJD3yyCFWtY-y0YqsCEC5oMw&sig2=SOmaR5eh3ny7SfWEx1n-5w) where you will find out how to train your own Haar classifier.

Hope I helped.